# Zero issues in Fortify report

Tags: fortify

I used the command

```
   sourceanalyzer -b myproj -scan -f myproj.fpr
```

to generate the scan report. (The project is built with ID "myproj" successfully) But it failed at 97% and giving the report with ZERO issues. Is it natural to have the Fortify report  with no issues, given it has scanned 1,979 files ? Or it meaned the scanning just failed?

Thank you,

-Cosmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to provide more information:

```
sourceanalyzer -b myproj -clean
sourceanalyzer -b myproj -debug-verbose -logfile TranslateLog.txt <your translation args here>
sourceanalyzer -b myproj -debug-verbose -logfile ScanLog.txt -scan -f myproj.fpr
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look in the `.fortify` folder. Maybe it has written a log there. It's somewhere under `sca/sca.log` or so. (One of the handbooks contains the correct path). If not, or if it doesn't contain much details, you should add `-verbose` (should be enough) or `-debug` (if you like novels).

I bet it's a memory problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is not normal and the above posters have correct fact finding steps.  You have most likely not allocated any extra memory with the -Xmx parameter. PLease read the SCA User Guide to find out how to do this optimally.